# ¿Cómo copiar las filas de dos hojas de google sheet y llevarlas a otro google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un google spreadsheet en el cual almaceno los datos de un reporte de google adword en una hoja (Hoja1) y en otra hoja (Hoja2) almaceno los usuarios que han enviado un formulario de contacto.

Después en la hoja1 dónde está el reporte de google adwords hago un filtrado con unos id de la hoja2 y me quedan los datos filtrados del reporte por los usuario que han rellenado un formulario.

Una vez tengo filtrado todo quiero coger los datos de la hoja 1 y los datos de la hoja 2 y llevarlos a otro google sheet ya que no quiero que se líen los informes diarios.

Una vez hecho esto eliminamos los datos de las hojas 1 y 2 del antiguo google sheet.

El codigo que tengo hasta ahora es el que filtra los id es el siguiente:

```
function myFunction() 
{ 
    function Lento() 
    { 
        var h1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 1'); 
        var h2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 2'); 
        var rowsh1 = h1.getDataRange(); 
        var valuesh1 = rowsh1.getValues(); 
        var numColsh1 = rowsh1.getNumColumns(); 
        var numRowsh1 = rowsh1.getNumRows(); 
        var rowsh2 = h2.getDataRange(); 
        var valuesh2 = rowsh2.getValues(); 
        var numColsh2 = rowsh2.getNumColumns(); 
        var numRowsh2 = rowsh2.getNumRows(); 
        var idusuario = []; 
        var identificador = []; 

        //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja1 
        for (var r=1; r<valuesh2.length; r++) 
        { 
            var rowh2 = valuesh2[r], 
            nombre = rowh2[1], 
            email = rowh2[2], 
            telefono = rowh2[3], 
            mensaje = rowh2[4], 
            urllanding = rowh2[5], 
            fechausuario = rowh2[6]; 
            idusuario[r] = rowh2[0];//Guardamos los gclid del usuario en un         array 
        } 

        //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja2 
        for (var r=1; r<valuesh1.length; r++) 
        { 
            var rowh1 = valuesh1[r], 
                palabraclave = rowh1[1], 
                ciudad = rowh1[2], 
                fecha = rowh1[4], 
                pais = rowh1[5]; 
                identificador[r] = rowh1[0];//Guardamos los gclid en un array 
       } 

       for (var i=identificador.length-1;i>0;i--) 
       { 
           var encontrado = false; 
           for (var y=1;y<idusuario.length;y++) 
           { 
               if (identificador[i]== null || idusuario[y] == null) continue; 
               if (identificador[i] == idusuario[y]) 
               { 
                   Logger.log("encontramos el " + i); 
                   Logger.log("identificador " + identificador[i]); 
                   Logger.log("idusuario " + idusuario[y]); 
                   encontrado = true; 
                   break; 
              } 
           } 

           if (!encontrado) 
           {
               Logger.log("eliminamos el " + i); 
               h1.deleteRow(i+1); 
           } 
       } 
   } 

   Lento(); 
}
```

Y ahora el código que tengo para copiar y pegar los datos a otro sheet de las dos hojas y eliminar los datos de estas hojas es el siguiente:

```
function Exportar() 
{
    var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Xl4pWgPpPdzk7vLyrrdtEx4JV1wSvrhTYrp-z8OhLTY");
    var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14ilkiECtg4lRoLxZBVfFXnoYFISAuQ2-dDIoxOz3qXc");
    var hoja1 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); //Nombre de las hoja 1
    var hoja2 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 2"); //Nombre de la hoja 2
    var hoja1sheet2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName("DatosReporteUsuario");
    var datoshoja1 = hoja1.getDataRange().getValues();
    var datoshoja2 = hoja2.getDataRange().getValues();

    for(var i=0; i<datoshoja1.length; i++)
    {    
         hoja1sheet2.appendRow([datoshoja1[i][0], datoshoja1[i][1], datoshoja1[i][2], datoshoja1[i][3], datoshoja1[i][4],datoshoja1[i][5]]); 
    }   

    for(var i=0; i<datoshoja2.length; i++)
    {    
        hoja1sheet2.appendRow([datoshoja2[i][0], datoshoja2[i][1], datoshoja2[i][2], datoshoja2[i][3], datoshoja2[i][4],datoshoja2[i][5]]); 
    } 
    hoja1.clear();
    hoja2.clear();
    // hoja1.getRange(2, 1, nuevosvalores.length, hoja1.getLastColumn()).setValues(nuevosvalores);
}
```

El problema de este código me coge los datos de la primera hoja me los copia pero no los pega correctamente ya que en una celda me da un error y los datos de la hoja 2 me salen abajo de los datos copiados de la hoja 2 y no al lado como corresponde

Os muestro la imagen del resultado[image: Resultado imagen copiar y pegar]

Comment: Hola Aitor! ¿Podrías compartir el código de cada paso? Así mantenemos el formato que ya tienes (y no se cerrará la pregunta como No está claro lo que se pregunta =P). Cuándo veamos el código te podemos ayudar mucho más fácil.

Comment: Hola @MiquelColl ya he editado el código y he puesto el resultado que me sale me falta solo poner los resultados de la hoja dos al lado y no debajo es decir en la columna g deberían de empezar los datos de la segunda columna

Comment: @MiquelColl he realizado el codigo que funciona casi a la perfección, he realizado dos for en la funcion exportar que son los fors que debería de hacer una vez he realizado el filtrado de los id. el primer for es para recoger los datos de la hoja 2 y guardarlos en un array y el segundo for es para insertar las variables, lo he realizado con `getRange().setValues()`. Pero cuando lo inserta lo inserta en la fila 1 y no en la 2 ya que en la fila 1 van las cabeceras. Ejemplo del For: `for(var i=1; i<datoshoja2.length; i++){hoja1sheet2.getRange('G'+i).setValue(nombre[i]);}`

Comment: Ya entiendo el porque me los pone, ahora lo que no se es como sumarle +1 a la i del `getRange('G'+i)`.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado ponemos ` hoja1sheet2.getRange('G'+(i+1)).setValue(nombre[i]);` y nos lo pone donde toca ahora publico respuesta y me confirmas si esta bien

Answer (score 2):

La solución a este problema es:

1-Hemos de guardar los datos de la hoja 2 en array.

2-Una vez que los tenemos guardados los vamos introduciendo uno a uno con el comando ``

3- en el `` le hemos de sumar uno a la variable para que así nos lo ponga en la fila que nos toca.

Os dejo el código completo por si alguien le sirve

```
function Exportar() {
var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Xl4pWgPpPdzk7vLyrrdtEx4JV1wSvrhTYrp-z8OhLTY");
var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14ilkiECtg4lRoLxZBVfFXnoYFISAuQ2-dDIoxOz3qXc");
var hoja1 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); //Nombre de las hoja 1
var hoja2 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 2"); //Nombre de la hoja 2
var datoshoja1 = hoja1.getDataRange().getValues();
var datoshoja2 = hoja2.getDataRange().getValues();
var nombre =[];
var email =[];
var telefono =[];
var mensaje =[];
var urllanding =[];
var fechausuario =[];
var idusuario =[];

 var hoja1sheet2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName("DatosReporteUsuario");

 for(var i=0; i<datoshoja1.length; i++){    

 hoja1sheet2.appendRow([datoshoja1[i][0], datoshoja1[i][1], datoshoja1[i][2], datoshoja1[i][3], datoshoja1[i][4],datoshoja1[i][5]]); 
}   
for(var i=0; i<datoshoja2.length; i++){ 
var rowh2 = datoshoja2[i]; 
nombre[i] = rowh2[1];
email[i] = rowh2[2]; 
telefono[i] = rowh2[3]; 
mensaje[i] = rowh2[4]; 
urllanding[i] = rowh2[5]; 
fechausuario[i] = rowh2[6]; 
idusuario[i] = rowh2[0];
}
for(var i=1; i<datoshoja2.length; i++){
hoja1sheet2.getRange('G'+(i+1)).setValue(nombre[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('H'+(i+1)).setValue(email[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('I'+(i+1)).setValue(telefono[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('J'+(i+1)).setValue(mensaje[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('K'+(i+1)).setValue(urllanding[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('L'+(i+1)).setValue(fechausuario[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('M'+(i+1)).setValue(idusuario[i]);

hoja1.clear();
hoja2.clear();
// hoja1.getRange(2, 1, nuevosvalores.length, hoja1.getLastColumn()).setValues(nuevosvalores);

}
}
```

Si tenéis otra manera mejor de hacerlo ponerla

Comment: Yo lo veo bien! El poder de *debuggar* te ha solventado el problema :). Un saludo!

Comment: Si la verdad que si, Gracias

Comment: Hola @MiquelColl hay un error ya que esto como lo tiene que hacer diariamente los registros se me solapan no los añade uno debajo del otro y a parte coge todo lo que hay en el primer sheet de la hoja2

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es un copy/paste de una fila:

```
var celdas_historico = sheet_principal.getRange(
  i + 1, 1, 1, sheet_principal.getLastColumn( )
).getValues( );

sheet_historico.getRange(
  sheet_historico.getLastRow( ) + 1, 1, 1, sheet_principal.getLastColumn( )
).setValues( celdas_historico );
```