# ¿Cómo pasar datos entre todas las spreadsheet que contenga un folder en google spreadsheets con Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me gustaria saber como puedo copiar o importar datos entre spreadsheets que se encuentren entre el mismo folder, mas en especifico que varias spreadsheet copien datos a una solo spreadsheet y pueda definir el rango de celdas a copiar y a que rangos de celdas se copien. tengo el siguiente codigo que encontre en un tutorial...

```
function onOpen() {  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var pasteSheet = [ {name: "Paste Sheet", functionName: "copySheet"}];
ss.addMenu("Copy to Spreadsheets", pasteSheet);
}

function copySheet() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId());
var sourceFolder = sourceFile.getParents().next();
var folderFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
var thisFile; 

while (folderFiles.hasNext()) {
thisFile = folderFiles.next();
if (thisFile.getName() !== sourceFile.getName()){
var currentSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisFile.getId());
sheet.copyTo(currentSS);
currentSS.getSheets()[currentSS.getSheets().length-1].setName('THIS WAS 
COPIED');
}     
};    
}
```

Este código lo que hace es que copia una hoja de una spreadsheet y lo pega en todos las demas spreadsheets que se encuentren en el mismo folder, yo lo que estoy intentando hacer y no logro es que se copien o importen datos de varias spreadsheets, especificando el rango y se peguen en una spreadsheet en un rango en específico

Comment: Publicación cruzada en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51770396/1595451

Comment: Haz cambiado prácticamente por completo el código. Como mencionaba en un comentario en mi respuesta, las preguntas de seguimiento deberían ser publicadas como nuevas preguntas en lugar de editar la pregunta original. Considerando esto voy revertir el cambio realizado hace unos minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencioné en [mi respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773253/1595451) a [la publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51770396/1595451) sobre lo mismo en inglés, lo que visto que es usado más comúnmente son los métodos

- `getRange` para tomar los rangos de origen y destino
- `getValues` para tomar los valores
- `setValues` para pasar los valores.

Pregunta relacionada en Stack Overflow en español

- [¿Cómo copiar las filas de dos hojas de google sheet y llevarlas a otro google sheet?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21643/65)

Referencia

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: Que tal Ruben Gracias por la ayuda una disculpa por poner la misma pregunta en ingles, es que creí que en el server ingles obtendría mas respuestas, disculpa mas que nada ya solucione como pasar datos pero ahora los datos que me trae son solo los de una hoja y no de varias y no se porque pero es de la hoja que acabo de editar. no se si me puedas ayudar a como evitar que eso pase, ya edite la pregunta conforme a el nuevo código. Gracias y saludos

Comment: @LuisAvl No hay problema por publicar la pregunta en dos o más idiomas, sin embargo en consideración de los usuarios que visiten los sitios relacionados sería muy amable el que indicaras que así lo has hecho. Si mi respuesta te pareció clara y que respondió la pregunta original, por favor acéptala. Ref. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien respondió mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). En cuanto a las preguntas de seguimiento (preguntas derivadas de una respuesta) en lugar de editar la pregunta original deberías publicar una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver como extraer datos de una carpeta que contenga un número de spreadsheets a una sola spreadsheet. para eso utilice el siguiente código pero solo copia los datos de una sola hoja. Sólo tengo que encontrar la forma de que no sobrescriba los datos.

```
  function getData() {
     var files = 
     DriveApp.getFolderById("1w86dQcDzTWC6qcCVGaEUo1tIuaaZkWEC").getFiles()
       while (files.hasNext()) {
         var file = files.next();
         var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());


  var sourceSheet = shoot.getSheets()[0];

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C");
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange("D2:D");
  var sourceValues2 = sourceRange2.getValues();


  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange("D2:D");
  destRange.setValues(sourceValues);

  var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange("E2:E");
  destRange2.setValues(sourceValues2);

}

}
```

Comment: Está bien que respondas tu propia pregunta para que compartas tu solución, pero no deberías usar una respuesta para hacer preguntas de seguimiento. Estas deben publicarse como nuevas preguntas.